# Flutter Local Notification - How can i make a notification that goes to a file that i downloaded?

Tags: flutter, download, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm creating a button that initiates a file download. Once the download is completed, a notification appears to confirm the download's success. However, I'd like to be able to click on the notification and have it open the file folder.

I attempted to use flutter_local_notifications, but it doesn't offer any functionality to achieve this.

Edit: I use `open_file_plus` and `flutter_downloader` it just works. :|

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.